# Does whoami /groups query the DC?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, active-directory

How does `whoami /groups` work? Does it connect to the DC and get the information from there or is that information cached on the computer somewhere and retrieved by the command? If it is stored somewhere, where is that?

Comment: Pull your network cable out and run it; does it still show your Domain groups? (hint: it does)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 It does. Also, it doesn't immediately show groups after they have been added in AD. Do you know where that information is stored in the file system/registry? That's what interests me the most :)